# Problem: restarting App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, restart

My App is a view-based application. At the beginning I show my logo and after a delay of a few seconds it changes into another view. from then on the user can switch to a lot of different views. 
Sooooo.. My Problem: The thing is, when I restart my App. [..well closing and reopen by touching the icon..] the app itself doesnt restart in the sence of jumping to the very first view. to the contrary: at restart the user just returns to the last view that was open.
So I dont know why this is. 
Is it normal to somehow manually tell the app to return to the very first view after restart? And if so, how do I have to do that?

PS.
I have so no idea what to do.. Maybe my problem has to do with the timer i used in the first view to change after a delay of time?

Please, is there anyone, who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that, as of iPhone 4, returning to the home screen does not terminate your app. It's just made inactive, so opening it again reactivates it. In most cases, this is a good thing. If it doesn't work for your app, you can add the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key to your Info.plist with a value of YES.

(As I said, you should only do this if it really helps usability. If it's just about getting your splash screen shown again, most users and possibly Apple will frown upon it.)

Answer (score 0):

iOS 4.0 and greater have a fast-start thing that allows apps to restart back from where they were upon restarting. There are several ways to deal with this:

1.) your App Delegate receives info about being but into the background and resumed. `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` and `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` are the relevant functions here. Check the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).
2.) You can also disable the background, inactive state completely by including `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` in you Info.plist as Chuck already pointed out.

Overall, you should check the [application state](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) docs on Apple's Side.